# How to prove $(p\log p+q\log q)^2\leq -\log(p^2+q^2)\log 2$?

Tags: inequality, entropy, renyi-entropy

I came up with the following conjecture while tacking [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769290/prove-that-xxyy-geq-dfracx2y22):

> **Conjecture.** Let $p \in [0, 1]$ and $q = 1-p$. Then
>
> $$ (p \log p + q \log q)^2 \leq -\log(p^2 + q^2)\log 2 $$

A numerical experiment shows that this must be true, but I have no idea whether this can be proved with a clever idea or it requires some dirty work.

[image: Comparison]

**Remark 1.** Jensen's inequality gives

$$ -\log(p^2 + q^2) \leq -(p \log p + q \log q) \leq \log 2, $$

telling that the conjecture is not quite trivial.

**Remark 2.** Writing $\mathrm{H}_{\alpha}(p) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(p^{\alpha}+q^{\alpha})$ for the binary [Rényi entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) (with the cases $\alpha=0,1,\infty$ being defined via limit), the above inequality is equivalent to

$$ \mathrm{H}_1(p)^2 \leq \mathrm{H}_2(p)\mathrm{H}_0(p). $$

Numerical experiment suggests that $\alpha \mapsto \log \mathrm{H}_{\alpha}(p)$ is convex, from which the above inequality will follow. However, logarithmic Rényi entropy, $\log \mathrm{H}_{\alpha}(\mathcal{D})$ as a function of $\alpha$ for a general discrete distribution $\mathcal{D}$, is not necessarily concave, meaning that the above inequality is specific to binary case (i.e., $\mathcal{D}$ is Bernoulli).

Of course, it is possible that this inequality has nothing to do with entropy-based interpretation at all.

**Remark 3.** A slightly weaker inequality,

$$ \mathrm{H}_1(p) \leq \frac{\mathrm{H}_2(p) + \mathrm{H}_0(p)}{2},$$

can be proved directly by differentiation. (This is weaker because it can be proved assuming the conjecture and applying AM-GM inequality.)

Comment: @MartinR, My mistake, thanks for pointing out! It's fixed now :)

Comment: You have really to prove that for $0\le x\le1$ (you can do it for $0\le x\le 0.5$ if you want)
$$f(x)=(x\log(x)+(1-x)\log(1-x))^2+\log(2)\log(2x^2-2x+1)\ge0$$ and it is not conjectural but true as you can verify plotting the corresponding curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a ugly proof*:

The non-trivial case is that $pq > 0$.

We use the result in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253006/new-bound-for-am-gm-of-2-variables). @Erik Satie's pointed out this result in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769290/prove-that-xxyy-geq-dfracx2y22/4769388#4769388).

**Fact 1**: Let $x, y > 0$. Then
$$x\ln x + y\ln y \ge (x + y)\ln(x + y - \sqrt{xy}).$$

By Fact 1, we have
$$p \ln p + q \ln q \ge \ln(1 - \sqrt{pq}). \tag{1}$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\ln^2(1 - \sqrt{pq}) \le - \ln(p^2 + q^2)\ln 2. \tag{2}$$

Let $u = \sqrt{pq}\in [0, 1/2]$. (2) is written as
$$\ln^2(1 - u) \le -\ln(1 - 2u^2)\ln 2. \tag{3} $$

It suffices to prove that, for all $u\in [0, 1/2]$,
$$-\ln (1 - u) \le \sqrt{-\ln(1 - 2u^2)\ln 2}.\tag{4}$$

**Fact 2**: For all $u\in [0, 1/2]$,
$$\sqrt{-\ln(1 - 2u^2)\ln 2}
\ge (8\ln 2 - 4)u^3 + (8 - 12\ln 2)u^2 + (6\ln 2 - 3)u.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 2, it suffices to prove that
$$-\ln(1 - u) \le (8\ln 2 - 4)u^3 + (8 - 12\ln 2)u^2 + (6\ln 2 - 3)u. \tag{5}$$

Let
$$f(u) := (8\ln 2 - 4)u^3 + (8 - 12\ln 2)u^2 + (6\ln 2 - 3)u + \ln (1 - u).$$

We have
$$f'(u) = \frac{(1-2u)^2}{1-u}[6\ln 2 - 4 - (6\ln2 - 3)u].$$
Let $u_0 = \frac{6\ln 2 - 4}{6\ln 2 - 3}$. We have $f'(u_0) = 0$,
and $f'(u) > 0$ on $[0, u_0)$, and $f'(u) < 0$ on $(u_0, 1/2)$.
Also, $f(0) = f(1/2) = 0$.
Thus, $f(u) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1/2]$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

It suffices to prove that
$${-\ln(1 - 2u^2)\ln 2}
\ge \left[(8\ln 2 - 4)u^3 + (8 - 12\ln 2)u^2 + (6\ln 2 - 3)u\right]^2.$$

Let
$$F(u) := -\ln(1 - 2u^2)\ln 2 - \left[(8\ln 2 - 4)u^3 + (8 - 12\ln 2)u^2 + (6\ln 2 - 3)u\right]^2.$$

We have
$$F'(u) = \frac{2u(1 - 2u)}{1 - 2u^2} G(u)$$
where $G(u)$ is a quintic polynomial.

We can prove that there exists $0 < u_1 < 1/2$ such that $G(u) > 0$ on $(0, u_1)$, and $G(u) < 0$ on $(u_1, 1/2)$.
(*Note*: We omit the proof here. )

Thus, we have $F'(u) > 0$ on $(0, u_1)$,
and $F'(u) < 0$ on $(u_1, 1/2)$.
Also, $F(0) = F(1/2) = 0$.
Thus, $F(u) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1/2]$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for the hard work! It would take time for me to swallow this argument. I will make sure to accept it once I read it and no better solution appears.

Comment: @SangchulLee It is not nice (e.g. Proof of Fact 2). Perhaps there is a nice proof related to some solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763483/elegant-proof-of-x-log-2-frac1x1-x-log-2-frac11-x-geq-1-1).